# Average time between sql edits in php

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a system to track inventory items.

The sql table is set up as follows:

```
Unique ID | Order number | Location | TimeStamp
```

Every time an order `moves`, a new entry is created with the same order number with the `new location` and `timestamp`.

Now I need to find the average time required for order to move from one location to another, say from Location `Warehouse` to `Pickup Depot`.

I am trying to work on the query and I have this so far.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
  MIN(TimeStamp), 
  MAX(TimeStamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0) 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Status = 'Delivered' 
  AND TimeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
```

The works really well if the table only had one order number, the moment we add more table numbers the `average` goes off.

I need it to only look at the timestamp difference for each order number, while currently I think its looking at the whole table.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Apologize for posting this question twice, the previous post did not contain enough information.

Thanks again.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
  MIN(TimeStamp), 
  MAX(TimeStamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0) 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Status = 'Delivered' 
  AND TimeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
  GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

The above query returns the timedifference in different rows in sql (with the following error " Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.". The table  has one column named "IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TimeStamp), MAX(TimeStamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)" with the time difference for various orders arrange in rows. Now I am trying to get their average with the output code.

Am outputting the results with the following code:

```
$row_cnt = $result2->num_rows;
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $processingseconds = $row2['IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TimeStamp), MAX(TimeStamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)'] + $processingseconds;
}
print "Current Processing Time: ";

$processingseconds = $processingseconds/$row_cnt;
$processingminutes = $processingseconds/60;

echo $processingminutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Group by condition to your query.

```
GROUP BY Order_Number_column
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
  MIN(TimeStamp), 
  MAX(TimeStamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0) 
FROM TableName
WHERE Status = 'Delivered' 
  AND TimeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
GROUP BY Your_Order_Number_column
```

Comment: that only returns the timedifference for the most recent order

Comment: How are you outputting it? 
Please provide more information as to what you are trying to do with it and how/where you want it to show, for better understanding exactly how you want it to work :).

Comment: now I get why you were asking about the output code. Thanks user2267175. I think I am heading in the right direction but feel free to jump in with the solution.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't really see the problem..
Have you tried running the query with a DB editor tool? 
Heidisql or w/e you have, check if the query also only returns one result there, 
if it does, then something is wrong in the query, 
if it returns several results, something is wrong with the php outputting..

Comment: See my edit above, the query is working fine. I am just not able to use it to get the desired results.

Comment: The query is returning two results (for the two orders I have in my system). I am having trouble getting the average of the two. my current code only processes the last row.

Comment: Check my edit, What exactly do you have in your database?
I just got confused, in order for the code to work properly, you need to have atleast 2 rows with the same order number,

Comment: Also, is the Unique ID column set as primary key?

Comment: problem resolved, see updated output code. needed to add on the processingtime rather than overwriting it.

Comment: to answer your unique id question, the unique id column is set as primary key. the table that comes out as output for my query does not have a primary key. thanks for all your help guys, could not have figured this out without your help and patience.

Comment: Ahh Awesome, just my confusion then :)